# How to limit the max "total" file size in dropzone.js?

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, upload, dropzone.js

Currently I use dropzone to handle the file upload in Jquery. So far it works fine.

The only problem is that, in the configuration there is a maxFileSize options , it limit the "single" file size.

And as the server (php.ini) also has a "total" file size limitation, I wonder how to limit that in the dropzone.js?

Thanks a lot.

http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration-options

Comment: You can control the maximum file upload size per file, while also controlling the maximum number of files uploaded.  Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I only see `maxfilesize`, `paralleluploads` and `maxfiles`

I think you may need to keep track of the file sizes as they're added, maybe using

```
this.on("addedfile", function(file) { // perform task // });
```

... tally the file sizes and disable the submit button if the total file size is exceeded.

```
document.getElementById('dropsubmit').disabled = false;
```

There are "addedFile" and "removedFile" events you could use to alter a variable tracking the file size as files are added and removed.  depending on the cumulative size, set the submit button to true or false.

Answer (score 4):

I found this workaround defining the accept function:

```
var totalsize = 0.0;
$("div#dropzone").dropzone({ 
    accept: function(file, done) {
        if (totalsize >= MAX_TOTAL_SIZE) {
            file.status = Dropzone.CANCELED;
            this._errorProcessing([file],  "Max limit reached", null);
        }else { 
            done();
        }
    }
    init: function() {
        this.on("addedfile", function(file) { 
            totalsize += parseFloat((file.size / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2));
        });
        this.on("removedfile", function(file) {
            if(file.upload.progress != 0){
                totalsize -= parseFloat((file.size / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2));
            }
        });
        this.on("error", function(file) {
            totalsize -= parseFloat((file.size / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2));
        });
    }
});
```

where MAX_TOTAL_SIZE is the max value that dropzone shall not exceed.

Comment: This is valid except that you don't need the "error" callback. Or it should be handled differently. The "error" callback will remove the total size, but the file preview will still remain and if the user clicks "Remove file" then the file size will be removed a second time causing an incorrect calculation.

Comment: in addition to the problem explained by marcus.salinas, the total size will not decrease when we delete a file; the if(file.upload.progress != 0){...} cannot logically be interpreted by me. I think if we change this line to: if (file.upload != undefined) both problem will be solved.

Comment: As a matter of fact the code above (by Andrea Falco) seems good when the Dropzone`s config is  "autoProcessQueue: true"

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit late but maybe someone else need this.
Well, you need to create a new variable "totalSize" in the init function.
Add an event listenner to the fileAdd to increase size and another one to substruct, then a little controle before you send the request to show an error, i'm bad with english so here is an example :

```
...
init: function() {
   var totalsize = 0.0;
 ...
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
 ... 
// increment total size when we add a file (in Mb)
    totalsize += parseFloat((file.size / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2));

//substruct the size of the removed file
      removeButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      ...
         _this.removeFile(file);
      totalsize -= parseFloat((file.size / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2));
     ...                      
      });
  ...             
  });
//and an event for the submission to controle before submit don't forget to prevent default
this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {

if (totalsize <= 20) {
      //do the request
       }else { // else show the error
        $('#error').show();
       $('#error').text('Oooops ! total files size must be less then 20Mb');

                        }
                  });
}
```

Maybe it's no so clear, so there is a full code example, in my code i'm adding a styled remove button so don't forget to delete it:

```
init: function() {
                    var totalsize = 0.0;
                    dzClosure = this; // Makes sure that 'this' is understood inside the functions below.

                      // for Dropzone to process the queue (instead of default form behavior):
                      document.getElementById("submit-all").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                          // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
                          e.preventDefault();
                          e.stopPropagation();
                          dzClosure.processQueue();
                      });
                    this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
                        // Create the remove button
                        var removeButton = Dropzone.createElement("<a href='javascript:;'' class='btn red btn-sm btn-block'>Remove</a>");

                        // Capture the Dropzone instance as closure.
                        var _this = this;

                        // Listen to the click event
                        removeButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                          // Make sure the button click doesn't submit the form:
                          e.preventDefault();
                          e.stopPropagation();

                          // Remove the file preview.
                          _this.removeFile(file);
                          totalsize -= parseFloat((file.size / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2));
                          // If you want to the delete the file on the server as well,
                          // you can do the AJAX request here.
                        });

                        // Add the button to the file preview element.
                        file.previewElement.appendChild(removeButton);
                        //increment
                        totalsize += parseFloat((file.size / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2));


                    });

                                    //send all the form data along with the files:
                      this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {

                          if (totalsize <= 20) {
                            console.log(totalsize);
        //u can append formData here too
                            formData.append("something", jQuery("#something").val());
                          }else {
                              $('#error').show();
                              $('#error').text('Oooops ! total files size must be less then 20Mb');

                            }
                      });
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to modify your php.ini (that php.ini from apache , not from php) , because in dropzoneJS , i think is enough 500mb to store one time

search there the post_max_size ..let's say put it 100M , and

upload_max_filesize = 50M ... or how do you prefer !

Good luck with it , and I hope it's helpfully !