# How to calculate the total sizes for all files uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, dropzone.js

I'm using the following previous SO question to guide me with this. However, I am getting NaN instead of the total file size in the console log.

[How to calculate all files size uploaded in dropzone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38283801/how-to-calculate-all-files-size-uploaded-in-dropzone)

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
var dropFileSizes = acceptedFiles, dropTotal=0;
$.each(dropFileSizes, function(file){
    dropTotal+=file.size;
});
console.log(dropTotal);
```

Full code:

```
function toggleUploadButton() {
    acceptedFiles = myDropzone.getAcceptedFiles();
    queuedFiles = myDropzone.getQueuedFiles();
    rejectedFiles = myDropzone.getRejectedFiles();
    allAcceptFiles = acceptedFiles.values();

    var dropFileSizes = acceptedFiles, dropTotal=0;
    $.each(dropFileSizes, function(file){
        dropTotal+=file.size;
    });
    console.log(dropTotal);
}
```

Trying to get the total outside of the `toggleUploadButton` function:

```
var dropTotal = 0;
var dropFileSizes = acceptedFiles;
function toggleUploadButton() {
    acceptedFiles = myDropzone.getAcceptedFiles();
    allAcceptFiles = acceptedFiles.values();
    $.each(dropFileSizes, function(file){
        dropTotal+= (dropFileSizes[file].size || 0);
    });
}
console.log(dropTotal);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

you need to use

```
 dropTotal+=dropFileSizes[file].size;
```

if you want to see working example look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24r910uv/)

**`dropFileSizes` is an object, not an array** so you need to use the file variable inside the `$.each` as an index and access the file accordingly by `dropFileSizes[file].size;`

**OR**

if you want the file in same place you need to put `key` into `$.each` as below

```
 $.each(dropFileSizes, function(key, file){
        dropTotal+=file.size;       
    });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xg1nLs3v/1/)

**However, consider possibilities of undefined and null values**

Try this way

```
$.each(dropFileSizes, function(file){
    dropTotal+= (dropFileSizes[file].size || 0);
    // or  dropTotal+=(file.size || ) if you are using function(key, file){};  
});
```

In your code if  `dropFileSizes[file].size` contains something other than number math operation will fail which would result in `NaN` and your `dropTotal` would become `NaN`;

If you use `dropTotal+= (dropFileSizes[file].size || 0);` it would use 0 instead if something else such as `null` or `undefined` encounterd

**And to get `dropTotal`'s value outside of function**

you need to make sure that, the statement `console.log(dropTotal);` is executed after the call to `toggleUploadButton()`

Comment: It just comes up with 0 now. The file size still isn't outputting or totaling.

Comment: Can you console.log  `acceptedFiles` and see does it have files with size or not

Comment: Yes, it does: `[File]
0: File
accepted: true
dataURL: "data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAZABkAAD/"
height: 300
lastModified: 1516369295286
lastModifiedDate: Fri Jan 19 2018 08:41:35 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) {}
name: "AppExchange-Salesforce.png"
previewElement: div.dz-preview.dz-image-preview
previewTemplate: div.dz-preview.dz-image-preview
size: 40480`

Comment: The `dropTotal` variable is outputting only the last file size. It's doing it in my file and your fiddle.

Comment: No, check carefully, try adding files, I verified and it is the output in the alert is the total size of all the files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201681/discussion-between-irony-stack-and-paul).